# CSS to turn image into black and white with no grays

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to convert logos to black and white, without any grays and have gotten this far, but can't get rid of the gradient effects. I'd like to make it purely black and white (where the `mix-blend-mode: multiply` ultimately gets rid of the white background):

```css
.logo {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   filter: grayscale(1) contrast(1.5) brightness(1);
   mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://d2slcw3kip6qmk.cloudfront.net/marketing/blogs/press/8-tips-designing-logos-that-dont-suck/instagram-logo.png" class="logo" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `contrast(100)` to make it fully black and white. You can always tone it down a bit and use a lower setting such as `contrast(10)`.

```css
.logo {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   filter: grayscale(1) contrast(100) brightness(1);
   mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://d2slcw3kip6qmk.cloudfront.net/marketing/blogs/press/8-tips-designing-logos-that-dont-suck/instagram-logo.png" class="logo" />
```

Or, as @vals pointed out, you can use a slightly different `filter` to remove any gradient interference.

```css
.logo {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   filter: saturate(150) grayscale(1) contrast(10);
   mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://d2slcw3kip6qmk.cloudfront.net/marketing/blogs/press/8-tips-designing-logos-that-dont-suck/instagram-logo.png" class="logo" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to make anything non-white show up as black so I didn't get the missing portion in the bottom left, for example? I've also noticed that in other logos with text or varying grays, contrast seems to make it look fuzzy

Comment: You can use `invert(100%)` to flip a color to its opposite, but that would change the whole image. You will need to get a new image if you want to make it fully black and white without the "shine" on the bottom left. As for the fuzzyness, you can just lower the contrast level and it should make it less rugged (but will add some very subtle gradient color around the edges to make it look smoother - which would be some gray in this case).

Comment: try     filter: saturate(150) grayscale(1) contrast(10);

Comment: @vals that's great, thanks for mentioning this, I never realized saturate would fix the shine.

Comment: thanks @vals and @jake! i ended up landing on: `saturate(0) brightness(0.7) contrast(3)`

Comment: This was another helpful thread - I ended up with filter: saturate(0) brightness(.97) contrast(1.4) grayscale(1);